# Why can't I directly set an __int64 variable to -2500000000?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, visual-c++-6, int64

This program is written in VC++ 6.0 on a WindowsXP machine.

If I try to set an __int64 variable to -2500000000 directly, it is truncated to a 32bit value and the two's complement is taken.

```
__int64 testval;
testval = -2500000000;
```

At this point testval equals 1794967293 (110 1010 1111 1101 0000 0111 0000 0000 binary).

When I set the variable to 2500000000 and then multiply by negative one, it works:

```
__int64 testval;
testval = 2500000000;
testval *= -1;
```

The variable testval equals -2500000000 (1001 0101 0000 0010 1111 1001 0000 0000 binary).

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: MSVC6? Ouch! That hurts!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get a newer compiler.  VC6 standard compliance is VERY poor.

In VC6, try a suffix of `i64`, as in

```
__int64 toobig = -2500000000i64;
```

Found [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa245308(v=VS.60).aspx)!

Comment: Thanks, that would be the preferred method, but it's not an option at the moment.

Comment: @E: I think I have the solution for VC6, but I no longer have a copy installed where I can test it.

Comment: That works. Thanks!  That needs to be linked in their documentation for __int64.

Comment: @E: I agree, but I don't think Microsoft is fixing VC6 documentation anymore.  That they still care whether it installs and runs on new versions of Windows is a miracle.  And it seems to be on the old MSDN site which doesn't support community-contributed content, so I can't add it myself.

Answer (score 9):

The compiler is treating the constant 2500000000 as a 32-bit number.  You need to explicitly tell it to treat it as a `long int` by appending an `LL` to the end of the constant.  So, try instead:

```
testval = -2500000000LL;
```

**Update**:  Since your compiler doesn't support this, and you are stuck with VC6, try instead breaking it into a value that results from the product of two 32 bit numbers as in:

```
testval = -250000;
testval *= 10000;
```

Comment: Probably safer to make it `LL` rather than `L`

Comment: That (the compiler using a 32-bit type for that literal) is a violation of C++0x section `[lex.icon]`... anybody have the wording from C++03 or C++98?

Comment: C++03 probably isn't going to help much, considering Visual C++ 6 shipped in the late 90s.

Comment: Thanks,LL doesn't work, I get a compiler erro, and L makes no difference because a long in WindowsXP(32bit) is still only 32bits, the same as an int.

Comment: I think it's preferable to split a whole thousand instead of a myriad, also it's much easier to count (grasp) three instead of four zero.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is -2500000000LL. If it doesn't work, get a newer compiler.